# 3 model many to many relations, How do i update this type of relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

This is the pivot table,

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║ user_id ║ bag_id ║ book_id ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 1       ║ 1      ║ 1       ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 1       ║ 2      ║ 1       ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 1       ║ 2      ║ 2       ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 2       ║ 1      ║ 2       ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 2       ║ 2      ║ 3       ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 3       ║ 1      ║ 1       ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 3       ║ 1      ║ 2       ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 3       ║ 1      ║ 3       ║
╚═════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

This is the User model:

```
    public function bags(): BelongsToMany
     {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bags::class)->distinct();
     }

    public function books(): BelongsToMany
     {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Books::class)->distinct();
     }
```

I tried using sync(), like `$user->bags()->sync([1, 2, 3])` but this only sets the bags per user.
I want to update that in every user, he has different bags with different books.

Comment: In my experience, once you add a 3rd (or more) Model, it is no longer a `belongsToMany()` relationship, and you should treat this table as it's own Model (not sure what you would call yours though), and the Relationship would be a `hasMany()`, where a `User` can have multiple of these rows, one for each combination of `bag_id` and `book_id`, and the same for `Bag` (`user_id` and `book_id`) and `Book` (`bag_id` and `user_id`) combinations.

Comment: But it would change the behavior for each right? One user could have bag 1 and inside the bag is the books. Another user could have bag 1 but it has no books in it. Like the number of books is dependent on the user_id and bag_id.

Comment: That scenario is describing something completely different than what you have structured. That would be a `User` -> `hasMany()` `Bag`s, where each `Bag` -> `hasMany()` `Book`s.

Answer (score 0):

**What I assume you want:**
you have a User who has many Bags and each bag has many Books in it, if I'm in the right path so I suggest you to separate your pivot in this way:

**solution:**
instead of having only one pivot for both bag and book relation with user, you should have two pivots one for user and bags and the other for bag and books.

### How your new pivots will look like

**table_name:** user_bag 
[image]
this relation in the User model be like `$this->belongsToMany(Bag::class, 'user_bag')->distinct()`

**table name:** bag_book 
[image]
and this one in the Bag model will be like `$this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'bag_book')->distinct()`
and also this relation to the Book model : `$this->belongsToMany(Bag::class, 'bag_book')->distinct()`
now you have one to many relation among **a User and many Bags** and also **one Bag and Many books**

### How to use relations in the Controllers

1 - if you want to add a new bag or sync bags with a user, do this:

```
$user->bags()->attach([3])
$user->bags()->sync([1, 3])
```

2 - if you want to add or sync a book to all bags for all users who have that bag, do this:

```
Book::find(1)->bags()->attach([3]);
Book::find(1)->bags()->sync([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: So what I want to do is I want to update the bags or the books related per user.
For example, if User 1, has bag type 1, and it has 1 book in it, i want to add another book to the bag 1 of user 1, or I would also want to change the bag user 1 has and the books he could have. So like, the amount of books in a bag is dependent on the user_id and bag_id. The bag could be empty for the other users.

Comment: @bwy you cant have same bag for different users with different books, for example you can't have bag_1 with book_1 and book_2 for user_1, and have same bag_1 with book_3 and book_4 for user_2. but you can have standalone bags with different books and assign many bags to many users